# Getting returned list from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, windows

I have written a fairly simple web service that places the result set of a SQL query into a list. I am having trouble calling that list with the result set in it in the project where I am using the web service. I will place my code below:

**Web Service**

```
[OperationContract]
List<ViewDetails> ViewDetails();

[DataContract]
public class ViewDetails
{
    public string TitleView { get; set; }
    public string BodyView { get; set; }
    public string AuthorView { get; set; }

    public ViewDetails() { }
    public ViewDetails(string myTitleView, string myBodyView, string myAuthorView)
    {
        this.TitleView = myTitleView;
        this.BodyView = myBodyView;
        this.AuthorView = myAuthorView;
    }
}

 public List<ViewDetails> ViewDetails()
    {
        List<ViewDetails> details = new List<ViewDetails>();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 [My_Title] AS 'Title', [My_Body] AS 'Body', [My_Author] AS 'Author' FROM [My_table] ORDER BY [Date] DESC", conn);
        SqlDataReader rdrDetails = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            while (rdrDetails.Read())
            {
                details.Add(new ViewDetails(rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Title")).ToString(), rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Body")).ToString(), rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Author")).ToString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //exception
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return details;
    }
```

**Project where I am using web service**

```
 public async void ViewData()
 {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        string title = string.Empty;
        string body = string.Empty;
        string author = string.Empty;

        var res = await client.ViewDetailsAsync();
  }
```

I expect to be able to do something like this in my `ViewData` class so I can store the results in a variables and assign them to `textblocks`, etc..

```
title = res.TitleView;
```

But it is not allowing me to.... Does anyone see something that I am missing?

**NOTE**: This is a Universal Windows Application

Comment: your `catch` does not catch the exception. add `Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)` to it and see if it throws any exceptions. It looks like it does.

Comment: here is a basic step by step tutorial that you can use / follow http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576820/Basic-Step-by-Step-WCF-WebService

Comment: @KosalaW I know, but I have walked through the web service and it has no exceptions. It fills the list correctly. But you are correct.

Comment: Are you sure your variable `res` is null?

Comment: @Code why don't you use the debugger and step through the code and tell us what is and what isn't

Comment: @MethodMan I have stepped through with the debugger, it fills the list with the 2 results as I expect it to. The web service is doing as I expect it to. I am just unable to call the results in my project from my web service.

Comment: for just 2 rows returned .. why do you feel the need to call await
`var res = await client.ViewDetailsAsync();` now I am confused .. how do you know it's filling the list.. can you explain how you are testing this .. so you're saying that `res` has 2 items..?

Comment: No, the list "details" in my Webservice is holding 2 items(the result set from my query). "res" is an object of my "ViewDetails" class. I expect to be able to call the returned list in the "ViewDetails" class with the object of that class, "res".

Comment: Generally you want to avoid `async void` methods because any exception thrown won't be caught. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `DataMember` attribute in your  `ViewDetails` data contract properties.

```
[DataContract]
public class ViewDetails
{
   [DataMember]  
   public string TitleView { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string BodyView { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string AuthorView { get; set; }

    public ViewDetails() { }
    public ViewDetails(string myTitleView, string myBodyView, string myAuthorView)
    {
     this.TitleView = myTitleView;
     this.BodyView = myBodyView;
     this.AuthorView = myAuthorView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have it, I combined your solution and @siwydym67... Will test and post results

Answer (score 1):

You have missing that `res` is the `List<ViewDetails>`. `res` is not the instance of `ViewDetails`. So you should type `title = res[0].TitleView;`

Comment: That does not work... it does not pull in TitleView as a property

Comment: @Code: Same question again.. Did you check if `res` is null?

Comment: @KosalaW No it is not null. Has items in it once instantiated

Comment: Which means your web service is returning values..  Now what's your problem? You cannot figure out a way of accessing what's inside `res`? Add a watcher and try to understand the structure inside `res`. It's a collection of ViewDetails. So you should be able to loop through it.